# Disable controls when a specific combo-box item is selected

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing a fairly simple application in which a user can select certain inputs and it processes data. I am having a problem in when a user selects a specific string from one of the combo-boxes, it doesn't disable other controls. Basically when the user selects the combo-box and selects 'Initiate' all other controls should be disabled.

```
private void cbalpha_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var operatorcheckbox = (CheckBox)sender;
    foreach (Control cb in this.Controls)
        if ((StringtDataChoiceorSelect.SelectedItem != "(Initiate)")
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            cb.Enabled = operatorcheckbox.Checked;
        }
}
```

Comment: check the value of Selected Item

Comment: `SelectedIndexChanged` is the event of a `ComboBox`, so the `sender` should be `ComboBox` but you cast `sender` as `CheckBox` in the `cbalpha_SelectedIndexChanged` handler, it's funny. It should throw invalid cast exception. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to diable all the controls why are you using checkbox value to enable disable. It should be simply this

```
private void cbalpha_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        bool isEnabled = string.Compare(StringtDataChoiceorSelect.SelectedItem.ToString(),"(Initiate)",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0;
        foreach (Control cb in this.Controls)
            cb.Enabled = !isEnabled ;

    }
```

Comment: Do you think `sender` is of type `CheckBox` or `ComboBox`?

Comment: @KingKing yes you are right. That is wrong as well. didn't noticed. edited. Not required altogather.

Comment: Hi, sorry yes its a combo box, no idea why i had checkbox. With your solution the controls disable if any of the combo box items are selected opposed to disabling the controls only if 'initiate' is selected?

Comment: @user2637869 what is the value of StringtDataChoiceorSelect.SelectedItem? it means that you are not getting correct value in this field. place your debugger over it and see the value

Comment: its returning me the correct value, when i hover my debugger over i get "(Initiate)"

Comment: @user2637869 my mistake, I have updated the code. Note the ! before isEnabled.

Comment: That works great thank you , would it be a simple fix to make it so that the combo box can still operate so they can choose a different item.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    private void cbalpha_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var operatorcheckbox =(CheckBox)sender;
        foreach (Control cb in this.Controls)
        {
           if ((StringtDataChoiceorSelect.SelectedItem != "(Initiate)")
           {
               if(!cb.Enabled)
               {
                  cb.Enabled = true;
               }
           }
           else
           {
               cb.Enabled = false;
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you think `sender` is of type `CheckBox` or `ComboBox`?

Answer (score 0):

on SelectedIndexChanged event check if the selected objected is same on which you want to disable other control and then disable it.

```
protected void ddltext_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlPerc.SelectedValue.Equals("0.01"))
    {
        txtbox.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use delegates and events for this.

```
if(operatorcheckbox.Checked && 
    StringtDataChoiceorSelect.SelectedItem == "(Initiate)")
{
    EventHandler -= checkboxdelegate;
}
else
    EventHandler += checkboxdelegate;
```

You can add a method if there's controls you do not want to keep enabled.